# Build Linq queries and concatenate dynamically based on a table

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm summarizing data to build an alert system. This query counts how many points an employee has based on some criteria. The one below is working fine. However, the query can be longer depending on the User's location. For example, below I have only have 3 unions but  for other Employees' locations more unions may be needed. For example in Location B they may also want to add an alert if a ReasonTypeID == is 3 and any entries in the last 90 days.

So I was thinking on building a table that I can add parameters on a location by location basis. I've read about dynamic linq library and I can use that for the WHERE statements but how would I add another query concatenation on the fly?

Here is what I have now.

```
public class TMAlert
{
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public decimal? PointSummary { get; set; }
    public string WarningLabel { get; set; }
    public bool AlertFlag { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<TMAlert> tmAlert = (
    from a in allEntries
    where a.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) && a.ReasonTypeID == 1
    group a by new
    {
        a.EmpID,
        a.FullName,
        a.ReasonTypeID
    } into g
    select new TMAlert
    {
        EmpID = g.Key.EmpID,
        FullName = g.Key.FullName,
        WarningLabel = "Last 30 Days",
        PointSummary = g.Sum(a => a.Points),
        AlertFlag = (g.Sum(a => a.Points) >= 4) ? true : false
    }).Concat(from a in allEntries
              where a.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90) && a.ReasonTypeID == 1
              group a by new
              {
                  a.EmpID,
                  a.FullName,
                  a.ReasonTypeID
              } into g
              select new TMAlert
              {
                  EmpID = g.Key.EmpID,
                  FullName = g.Key.FullName,
                  WarningLabel = "Last 90 Days",
                  PointSummary = g.Sum(a => a.Points),
                  AlertFlag = (g.Sum(a => a.Points) >= 9) ? true : false
              }).Concat(from a in allEntries
                        where a.Date >= (
                        from o in allEntries
                        where o.EmpID == a.EmpID && a.WarningTypeID == 2
                        select (DateTime?)o.Date).Max()
                        group a by new
                        {
                            a.EmpID,
                            a.FullName,
                            a.ReasonTypeID
                        } into g
                        select new TMAlert
                        {
                            EmpID = g.Key.EmpID,
                            FullName = g.Key.FullName,
                            WarningLabel = "60 Since Warning type 2 ",
                            PointSummary = g.Sum(a => a.Points),
                            AlertFlag = (g.Sum(a => a.Points) >= 4) ? true : false
                        });
```

I was thinking to build a criteria table then build the queries on the fly based on the table. 
for example

```
for each entry in criteriaTable

add dynamic linq entry.Param
.concat(....

next....
```

is this possible or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: well concidering that there is quite some recurring code, you could start by refactoring the code into methods. I also don't think that `AlertFlag` should be part of the data, but maybe rather a part of the UI

Comment: yeah create a method then call the method inside the loop then just add the return results to the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to combine linq queries dynamically.  I use it to add conditional filters to my where statements when showing a filtered list of data.

I initialize the lambda expression like this

```
Expression<Func<CatalogItem, bool>> Filter = CatalogItem => true;
```

then as I go I add to it.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVal)) {Filter = Filter.Compose(CatalogItem => CatalogItem.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchVal), Expression.And);}
```

I may have different if conditions that cause me to add more and more to my filter then finally I want to apply that filter against my collection.

```
IQueryable<CatalogItem> FilteredList = Items.AsQueryable().Where(Filter);
```

In this case Items is a list of CatalogItems that was pulled from the database earlier. I am using IQueryable instead of just List<> cause I need to act on the results afterwards.

```
List<CatalogItem> Items;//fill Items list here;
```

I know this is in-line Linq as opposed to the structure you use but I really can't get into the other form of linq querying as this is so quick and dirty for me. If you have to use the other linq form these rules may still apply.